Bluetooth keyboards no longer recognized by Macbook Pro (Sonoma 14.5)
M1 Macbook Pro
OSX Sonoma 14.5
Keyboards that can't connect via Bluetooth:

Logi MX Keys Mini for Mac - previously connected for 1+ year
NuPhy Air06

I used to have two Bluetooth keyboards set up on my Macbook, one at work and one at home. I got a new keyboard for traveling and wasn't able to set it up yesterday — it never showed on the "Nearby Devices" panel.
I read about people maxing out their Bluetooth connections, but I had only six (two mouses, two headphones, two keyboards) to begin with. Regardless, I "forgot" both the keyboard connections to get down to four, with no "competing" keyboards. Still, I can't see either keyboard, this just hangs:

Two other routes I've tried:

Installing Logi Options+, the Logitech application for device setup, but it couldn't detect the Logi keyboard, either.
Resetting Bluetooth from the command line, sudo pkill bluetoothd

I'm currently using the NuPhy keyboard with a USB3 cable. However, with only two ports on the laptop and requiring an external monitor and camera, this isn't a viable long-term solution.
From everything I've read here and all my experience, Apple won't help me with anything - the most I can hope for is that it's resolved by an OSX update somehow, sometime.
So... Any ideas? Are there any additional command line actions I can take (like clearing a cache or deleting a library) that could help?
Thanks!

Hello. Do your other bluetooth devices connect and work correctly?
